# rewrite with nginx conf result 502 bad gateway

Tags: 7

My code is based on http://wiki.nginx.org/Drupal and the result is 502 bad gateway. I have tried so many ways but dont work.... how  i can solve this? thanks

```
server {
        listen 8093;
        server_name localhost;
        root /home/ITEP;

        # Enable compression, this will help if you have for instance advagg‎ module
        # by serving Gzip versions of the files.
        #gzip_static on;

        location = /favicon.ico {
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        location = /robots.txt {
                allow all;
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        # This matters if you use drush prior to 5.x
        # After 5.x backups are stored outside the Drupal install.
        #location = /backup {
        #        deny all;
        #}

        # Very rarely should these ever be accessed outside of your lan
        location ~* \.(txt|log)$ {
                allow 192.168.0.0/16;
                deny all;
        }

        location ~ \..*/.*\.php$ {
                return 403;
        }

        # No no for private
        location ~ ^/sites/.*/private/ {
                return 403;
        }

        # Block access to "hidden" files and directories whose names begin with a
        # period. This includes directories used by version control systems such
        # as Subversion or Git to store control files.
        location ~ (^|/)\. {
                return 403;
        }

        location / {
                # This is cool because no php is touched for static content
                try_files $uri @rewrite;
        }

        location @rewrite {
                # You have 2 options here
                # For D7 and above:
                # Clean URLs are handled in drupal_environment_initialize().
                rewrite ^ /index.php;
                # For Drupal 6 and bwlow:
                # Some modules enforce no slash (/) at the end of the URL
                # Else this rewrite block wouldn't be needed (GlobalRedirect)
                #rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                #NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
                fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/phpfpm.sock;
        }

        # Fighting with Styles? This little gem is amazing.
        # This is for D6
        #location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/imagecache/ {
        # This is for D7 and D8
        location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/styles/ {
                try_files $uri @rewrite;
        }

        location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
        }
}
```

I'm using drupal 7.... fresh install

Comment: While this might be Drupal question, I believe you would have better chance for an answer at http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ or http://serverfault.com/ (if you can meet their quality requirements, of course), because your problem requires nginx skills, and Drupal on nginx is not common.

Comment: It's almost definitely not a Drupal issue, smells like an FPM problem. Check your server logs (web and FPM), they should have more detailed information on what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

The location of file `phpfpm.sock` may vary depending on Operating System:

Try find the `phpfpm.sock` file on your server:

`find / -name php*fpm.sock`

and then change the following line

`fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/phpfpm.sock;`

to reference `phpfpm.sock` from the correct location.

Example (Ubuntu 14):

`fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;`